# How to group by all but except one column

Tags: sql, t-sql

i want to group my results except one column:

```
Select Name,Title,Date from Books group by Name,Title
```

i don't want to group by date because books might have same date

Comment: Add some sample table data and the expected result - as well formatted text.

Comment: you CANNOT do that, because in a grouped query, EVERY column must be included in the grouping OR must be aggregated by an aggregation function

Comment: And if there are multiple different dates, what do you want to do with them? Show the latest, the earliest or show them all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use

```
Select Name,Title,Date from Books group by Name,Title,Date;
```

or

```
Select distinct Name,Title,Date from Books;
```

for the same purpose. It wont make any difference as the dates are same.

if dates are not same then you can use any aggregate function to achieve the same. like:

```
Select Name,Title,max(Date)--any aggregate function based on logic 
from Books group by Name,Title,Date;
```

Comment: I dont want to group by Date

Comment: But i want to select it

Comment: `Select Name,Title,max(Date)--any aggregate function based on logic 
from Books group by Name,Title,Date;`

Comment: Don't group by date when you have that column as argument to a set function.

Answer (score 0):

Quick and dirty without knowing what type of ordering or specific date values you want to include or exclude:

```
Select b.Name, b.Title, b.Date From Books b
Join (Select Name, Title From Books Group By Name, Title) sub
    On sub.Name = b.Name And sub.Title = b.Title
```

Comment: Isn't this the same as including `Date` in the `group by` in the first place?

Answer (score 0):

These one is working as expected

```
  SELECT [Name]
          ,[Title]
         ,max(Date)
  FROM [Books].[dbo].[myBooks] group by [Name],[Title]
```

Comment: Do not aggregate and group by the same column

Comment: Ya i remove Date grouping Thanks @Degan